# Can't run Cygwin GUI applications from Cygwin Terminal

Tags: cygwin, xorg

I can't start Cygwin GUI applications from Cygwin Terminal, if I click "XWin Server" in the start menu after a while the server is up and there is this "X applications menu on :0" in the notification area, if I click a program, it also won't start.

If I wish to run a GUI app from the console, say 2048-qt, I will get this message:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-XeneiXenwes'
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Could not connect to any X display.
```

I Googled this error message and I found this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227889/cygwin-on-windows-cant-open-display

It mentions the packages xorg-server and xinit, when I installed Cygwin X11 was set to default and these two packages were installed by default.

Now if I run `startxwin` in the Terminal I can start GUI applications normally from the resultant menu, however I still cannot start GUI applications from another Cygwin Terminal, this is what the server outputs:

```
Welcome to the XWin X Server
Vendor: The Cygwin/X Project
Release: 1.20.10.0
OS: CYGWIN_NT-10.0-19042 DESKTOP-PD984VK 3.1.7-340.x86_64 2020-08-22 17:48 UTC x86_64
OS: Windows 10  [Windows NT 10.0 build 19042] (Win64)
Package: version 1.20.10-1 built 2020-12-21

XWin was started with the following command line:

/usr/bin/XWin :0 -multiwindow -auth
 /home/XeneiXenwes/.serverauth.1002

(II) xorg.conf is not supported
(II) See http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html for more information
LoadPreferences: /home/XeneiXenwes/.XWinrc not found
LoadPreferences: Loading /etc/X11/system.XWinrc
LoadPreferences: Done parsing the configuration file...
winDetectSupportedEngines - RemoteSession: no
winDetectSupportedEngines - DirectDraw4 installed, allowing ShadowDDNL
winDetectSupportedEngines - Returning, supported engines 00000005
winSetEngine - Multi Window or Rootless => ShadowGDI
winScreenInit - Using Windows display depth of 32 bits per pixel
winAllocateFBShadowGDI - Creating DIB with width: 1920 height: 1080 depth: 32
winFinishScreenInitFB - Masks: 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff
winInitVisualsShadowGDI - Masks 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff BPRGB 8 d 24 bpp 32
MIT-SHM extension disabled due to lack of kernel support
XFree86-Bigfont extension local-client optimization disabled due to lack of shared memory support in the kernel
glWinSelectGLimplementation: Loaded 'cygnativeGLthunk.dll'
(II) AIGLX: Testing pixelFormatIndex 5
GL_VERSION:     4.6.0 NVIDIA 461.72
GL_VENDOR:      NVIDIA Corporation
GL_RENDERER:    GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_SGI_make_current_read
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_MESA_swap_control
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_SGIX_pbuffer
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_multisample
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_SGIS_multisample
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_profile
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
(II) 670 pixel formats reported by wglGetPixelFormatAttribivARB
(II) 634 fbConfigs
(II) ignored pixel formats: 0 not OpenGL, 0 unknown pixel type, 36 unaccelerated
(II) GLX: Initialized Win32 native WGL GL provider for screen 0
winPointerWarpCursor - Discarding first warp: 960 540
(--) 5 mouse buttons found
(--) Setting autorepeat to delay=500, rate=31
(--) Windows keyboard layout: "00000409" (00000409) "US", type 4
(--) Found matching XKB configuration "English (USA)"
(--) Model = "pc105" Layout = "us" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
Rules = "base" Model = "pc105" Layout = "us" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
winInitMultiWindowWM - DISPLAY=:0.0
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - DISPLAY=:0.0
cat: /home/XeneiXenwes/.serverauth.1002: No such file or directory
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - xcb_connect() returned and successfully opened the display.
winClipboardThreadProc - DISPLAY=:0.0
winProcEstablishConnection - winInitClipboard returned.
winInitMultiWindowWM - xcb_connect () returned and successfully opened the display.
winClipboardProc - xcb_connect () returned and successfully opened the display.
Using Composite redirection
wglCreatePbufferARBWrapper error: Unknown error (c0070591)
SetupSysMenu: GetSystemMenu() failed for HWND 0x150bbe
wglCreatePbufferARBWrapper error: The parameter is incorrect.  (00000057)
IsOverrideRedirect: Failed to get window attributes
```

Now interesting enough if I run `xinit` in the terminal(while xwin server is down) it opens the server much quicker than `startxwin`, and it opens this window:

[image]

In it if I type `2048-qt` the application will start normally, and this is what it says:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-XeneiXenwes'

JIT is disabled for QML. Property bindings and animations will be very slow. Visit https://wiki.qt.io/V4 to learn about possible solutions for your platform.
libGL error: Screen is not Windows-DRI capable
qml: Started a new game
```

What might be the cause of this issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: try `startxwin -- -nowgl` as it seems the WGL is not working properly on your system

Comment: @matzeri Nope, I have tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: I have the impression that you are trying to run X application from Mintty. In that case see note at the bottom of:  http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using-local-apps.html

Comment: @matzeri Using `export DISPLAY=:0.0` solved my problem, please post it as an answer so that I can accept it.